# Compile Time vs Run time speed

Tags: c++, templates

Why is getting a number of the Fibonacci sequence at compile-time using templates much faster than run-time using a recursive function?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<unsigned long long int I>
struct Fib
{
    static const unsigned long long int val = Fib<I - 1>::val + Fib<I - 2>::val;
};

template<>
struct Fib<0>
{
    static const unsigned long long int  val = 0;
};

template<>
struct Fib<1>
{
    static const unsigned long long int  val = 1;
};

int main()
{
    cout << Fib<100>::val << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Are you asking about the speed difference between `int fib(int i) { /* if (i < 2) ... */ return fib(i-1) + dib(i-2); }` and your `Fib<i>` template?

Comment: Exactly  
Joel Niemelä

Comment: Basically, templates are run during compilation, while normal functions are not.
Let me write a more detailed answer, so I can have some code examples (not much space here in the comments)

Comment: There likely is no speed difference between the two if you properly enable optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursive function has all of its code executed at runtime (unless the compiler optimizes it).

A template is typically faster at runtime because all of its code is executed by the compiler itself and only the result is stored in the final executable, so there is no code executed at runtime at all.

So, this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<unsigned long long int I>
struct Fib
{
    static const unsigned long long int val = Fib<I - 1>::val + Fib<I - 2>::val;
};

template<>
struct Fib<0>
{
    static const unsigned long long int  val = 0;
};

template<>
struct Fib<1>
{
    static const unsigned long long int  val = 1;
};

int main()
{
    cout << Fib<100>::val << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Once compiled, will behave as-if you had written this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Fib_100
{
    static const unsigned long long int val = 3736710778780434371ull;
};

int main()
{
    cout << Fib_100::val << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Or simply:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << 3736710778780434371ull << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP isn't actually doing proper template meta-programming. That it happens to be calculated at compile-time here is a bit more subtle because all (intermediate) results are stored as constant-initialized static storage duration objects. Without the `const`s it would still be calculated at runtime and would actually have undefined behavior due to initialization order issues.

Comment: @user17732522 without the consts, the code shown wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Yes, but replace it e.g. with `inline` or out-of-line definitions. Or for a more subtle scenario: What if instead of using `+` directly OP had used a function `int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }`. Again the statics wouldn't have been constant-initialized. Basically what I am saying is that without `constexpr` this is kind of dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

### Compile-time evaluation

Templates are run at compilation time, while functions are run at run time.

This means that, in your code, `Fib<90>::val` is replaced by the value of fib(90) (2880067194370816120); no code is ever run.

On the other hand, a function isn't evaluated during compilation but only when your program is run. In the case of fib(90), this will take quite a while to run.

In some cases, the compiler can still optimize a normal function call. But this is not always the case, while templates are *always* run during compilation.

### Memoization

One other reason templates are faster than a simple recursive function is that templates inherently have "memoization". This means that Fib<1> is only ever calculated one time, even if it's called multiple times. This makes a big difference when you calculate the Fibonacci series. For example:
Let's say we want to calculate
`fib(5)`. To do so, we first have to calculate `fib(i-1)` and `fib(i-2)`, i.e. `fib(4)` and `fib(3)`. But in order to calculate `fib(4)`, we have to first calculate `fib(3)` and `fib(2)`. etc. Notice how we had to calculate `fib(3)` more than once? That's where memoization comes in. Memoization basically saves the return value, and then, the next time you call the function with the same argument, it just returns that value without having to calculate anything again. It could be implemented something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long mem[100];
unsigned long long fib(unsigned long long i) {
    if (mem[i]) return mem[i];
    return mem[i] = (i <= 1 ? i : fib(i - 1) + fib(i - 2));
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fib(90) << std::endl;
}
```

And if you run that now, it's much faster than just the simple recursive implementation!

Templates practically do the same thing: if you `write Fib<1>` once, it saves the result for the next time you use it.

---

### Overflow

Note that neither `Fib<100>::val` nor `fib(100)` will actually work - sure, they will compile, and even run, but the result will be incorrect! That's because of integer overflow: an `unsigned long long` can only hold values from `0` to `18446744073709551615` (8 bytes*), but the result of `fib(100)` is greater than that. C++ takes the 8 bytes it *can* fit and leaves the rest, which results in an incorrect answer.

---

Edit:

As @user17732522 pointed out, your `value` member should be a `constexpr`, not a `const`:

```
template <unsigned long long N>
struct Fib {
    static constexpr unsigned long long val = Fib<N-1>::val + Fib<N-2>::val;
};

// ... other cases ...
```

---

*`unsigned long long` is only guaranteed to be *at least* 8 bytes, but it *could* be more (although it usually isn't).

Comment: See comment on the other answer.

Comment: @user17732522 Yeah, just saw it, thanks, that's a good point.

Comment: Actually I would very much prefer `constexpr` or passing in template parameters instead. Then there is no risk for a mistake either and you have proper type information.

Comment: Does that still compile then? I'm pretty sure `Fib<100>` will overflow and constexpr does not allow UB.

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow It does compile, but it actually returns the wrong value (I didn't notice that, thank you!) I also just noticed I used an int in my example, not an unsigned long long. Oops! Thank you, I completely missed that somehow.
But the correct code (using an unsigned long long) would still compile because overflow on unsigned numbers isn't UB.

Comment: @JoelNiemelä right, unsigned, I was thinking `int` too.

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler computes every `Fib<??>::val` [just once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), regardless of enabled optimizations.

On the other hand, a naive implementation using a recursive function (assuming no optimizations) would repeatedly compute the same `fib(??)` number, way more times than than necessary.